# C11 - omitting potentially infinite loop by the compiler

Tags: c, language-lawyer, infinite-loop, c11

Assume the following code

```
struct a {
    unsigned cntr;
};

void boo(struct a *v) {
    v->cntr++;
    while(v->cntr > 1);
}
```

I wonder if the compiler is allowed to omit the `while` loop inside `boo()` due to the following statement in the C11 standard:

> An iteration statement whose controlling expression is not a constant expression,<sup>156)</sup> that performs no input/output operations, does not access volatile objects, and performs no synchronization or atomic operations in its body, controlling expression, or (in the case of a for statement) its expression-3, may be assumed by the implementation to terminate.<sup>157)</sup>
>
> ---
>
> <sup>157)</sup><sub>This is intended to allow compiler transformations such as removal of empty loops even when termination cannot be proven.</sub>

Can `v->cntr`, in the controlling expression, be considered as a *synchronization* since `v` may be a pointer to a global structure which can be modified externally (for example by another thread)?

Additional question.
Is the compiler allowed not to re-read `v->cntr` on each iteration if `v` is not defined as `volatile`?

Comment: `be considered as a synchronization since v may be a pointer to a global structure which can be modified externally ` It's a standard, it's all defined, synchronization operation is defined - modifying a global variable like in your code is not a synchronization operation.

Comment: @KamilCuk *A synchronization operation on one or more memory locations is either an acquire operation, a release operation, both an acquire and release operation, or a consume operation.* - I couldn't find the definition of *consume operation* but why reading globabl memory cannot be considered  a `consume operation`?

Comment: The compiler can do whatever it wants as long as the observable outcome is the same as for program executed on abstract C machine.

Comment: `couldn't find the definition of consume operation` `For memory_order_consume, a load operation performs a consume operation` https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.17.3p5

Comment: @tstanisl this is exactly the opposite in this case as I would expect the flow to stop/hang once `v->cntr` reaches value grater than 1. In the case described here, the flow will never stop since the compiler may drop the whole `while` loop

Comment: @AlexLop. yes.. assuming that the passage of eternity is an observable effect. I guess according to the C standard it is not.

Comment: @tstanisl It has to be. Let's assume I call `boo()` on each keyboard key press. I would expect it to hang after the second key press... but here comes the surprise of C11.

Comment: I don't think so. The eternity cannot be observed thus it is not an observable effect as it would require infinite time what it likely above the limits of any mortal observer. Therefore it should be "optimizable" to no op except some cases described in the standard like `while(1)`. You should use `volatile` or `_Atomic volatile` there.

Comment: @AlexLop. for this to work the access would have to be `volatile` qualified, and then the loop would not be optimized out.

Comment: @JensGustedt right. That would be expected without doubt as the C11 standard defines it explicitly "...*does not access volatile objects*..." so once `volatile` object is accessed, the optimization is not allowed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can v->cntr, in the controlling expression, be considered as a synchronization

No.

From [https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.4p5](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.4p5) :

> The library defines a number of atomic operations (7.17) and operations on mutexes (7.26.4) that are specially identified as synchronization operations.

So basically, functions from `stdatomic.h` and `mtx_*` from `thread.h` are synchronization operations.

> since v may be a pointer to a global structure which can be modified externally (for example by another thread)?

Does not matter. Assumptions like sound to me like they would disallow many sane optimizations, I wouldn't want my compiler to assume that.

If `v` were modified in another thread, then it would be unsequenced, that would just result in undefined behavior [https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.4p25](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.4p25) .

> Is the compiler allowed not to re-read v->cntr on each iteration if v is not defined as volatile?

Yes.

Comment: Other synchronization operations are most operations on atomic objects. So if the member `cntr` would be atomic, `boo` would wait forever until another thread ensures the condition.